# Implementing E Voting System using Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle

I am working on an E voting system based on Foo92 protocol. I am new to Bouncy Castle library. But I have to tell that this system based on blind signature with RSA Algorithm. This Scheme(FOO92) has a chart and I have Upload it for you. I want to know that how to sign blindly and verify it in Bouncy Castle library. Please Help me with my problem.
Thank you All.
  [image]

Please Notice that * operator is blinding operator. and / operator is unblinding operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have wrote a code with Bouncy Castle for FOO92 e-voting protocol.
Here is the Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Org.BouncyCastle;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Math;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Generators;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Signers;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FooTest
{
    class FooImplementing
    {
        private RsaBlindingEngine rsaBlindingEngine = new RsaBlindingEngine();
        private RsaBlindingFactorGenerator blindingFactorGenerator = new RsaBlindingFactorGenerator();
        private RsaBlindingParameters blindingParameteres;
        private RsaKeyPairGenerator aliceRsaKeyGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        private AsymmetricCipherKeyPair aliceKeyPair;
        private RsaKeyPairGenerator bobRsaKeyGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        private AsymmetricCipherKeyPair bobKeyPair;
        private byte[] inputMessage;
        public FooImplementing(string message)
        {
            inputMessage = getBytes(message);
            aliceRsaKeyGenerator.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 1024));
            aliceKeyPair = aliceRsaKeyGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
            //******************************************************************************
            bobRsaKeyGenerator.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 1024));
            bobKeyPair = bobRsaKeyGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
            //******************************************************************************
            blindingFactorGenerator.Init(bobKeyPair.Public);
            blindingParameteres = new RsaBlindingParameters((RsaKeyParameters)bobKeyPair.Public, blindingFactorGenerator.GenerateBlindingFactor());
        }

        public byte[] getBytes(string input)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[input.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(input.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return bytes;
        }

        public string GetString(byte[] bytes)
        {
            char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
            return new string(chars);
        }

        public byte[] blindTheMessage(TextBox t1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inputMessage.Length; i++)
            {
                t1.Text += inputMessage[i].ToString();
            }
            PssSigner messageBlinder = new PssSigner(rsaBlindingEngine, new Sha1Digest(), 15);
            messageBlinder.Init(true, blindingParameteres);
            messageBlinder.BlockUpdate(inputMessage, 0, inputMessage.Length);
            byte[] blindedMessage = messageBlinder.GenerateSignature();
            return blindedMessage;
        }

        public byte[] blindSignature(byte[] input)
        {
            RsaEngine rsaEngine = new RsaEngine();
            rsaEngine.Init(true, bobKeyPair.Private);
            byte[] blindSignedMessage = rsaEngine.ProcessBlock(input, 0, input.Length);
            return blindSignedMessage;
        }

        public byte[] unblindeTheSignedData(byte[] input)
        {
            rsaBlindingEngine.Init(false, blindingParameteres);
            byte[] messageForSending = rsaBlindingEngine.ProcessBlock(input, 0, input.Length);
            return messageForSending;
        }

        public bool verifyBlindSignature(byte[] input, TextBox t1)
        {            
            PssSigner verifier = new PssSigner(new RsaEngine(), new Sha1Digest(), 15);
            verifier.Init(false, bobKeyPair.Public);
            verifier.BlockUpdate(inputMessage, 0, inputMessage.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < inputMessage.Length; i++)
            {
                t1.Text += inputMessage[i].ToString();
            }
            return verifier.VerifySignature(input);
        }

        public byte[] signedWithRsa(byte[] input)
        {
            ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA1withRSA");
            signer.Init(true, aliceKeyPair.Private);
            signer.BlockUpdate(input, 0, input.Length);
            byte[] signedData = signer.GenerateSignature();
            return signedData;
        }

        public bool verifyRsaSignedData(byte[] input, byte[] signature)
        {
            ISigner verifier = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA1withRSA");
            verifier.Init(false, aliceKeyPair.Public);
            verifier.BlockUpdate(input, 0, input.Length);
            return verifier.VerifySignature(signature);
        }

    }
}
```

and here is steps of of running foo protocol. of course it doesn't have some of steps such as id sending but it's functionality is as true as Foo protocol

```
FooImplementing foo = new FooImplementing("Behzad");
var blindedMessage = foo.blindTheMessage(textBox2);
var userSignature = foo.signedWithRsa(blindedMessage);
if (foo.verifyRsaSignedData(blindedMessage, userSignature))
{
     var signedMessage = foo.blindSignature(blindedMessage);
     var unblindedMessage = foo.unblindeTheSignedData(signedMessage);
     MessageBox.Show(foo.verifyBlindSignature(unblindedMessage, textBox3).ToString());
 }
```

Notice That Text Boxes are for gathering result and isn't part of my program.
Thank you all.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer with us, Behzad. If you really created and tested that in 17 hours I guess you are doing alright :)